# Azure, Containers and horizontal scaling

Tags: azure, containers, azure-aks, azure-container-service

I am new to containers and Kubernetes. I am doing most of my testing in Azure.

I created a container and based on the load the container horizontally scale. The endpoint hosted in the container I built will have to deal with burst of requests. I expect the container to be most of the time sitting idle but, in my testing, it sometime have to scale out to multiple instances to handle the burst of requests.

In order to keep the cost of running the service down, I wonder if it is possible to scale down the number of instances of the container to 0 while keeping the ability to "wake-up" the container when requests are about to come in? How could I achieve that?

Comment: You're already paying for the nodes running, why scale down to 0 pod?  Have you looked at bursting to Azure Container Instances?  I'm not sure if this would help you scale down to 0 instance. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-scale

Comment: I agree with CSharpRocks. since you are paying for a NODE, running 1 replica shouldn't be of any differences. you can enable Cluster AutoScaler to burst your node count when you need more PODs (replicas) OR leverage the ACI (Virtual Nodes) feature of AKS

Answer (score 1):

AKS internally uses the horizontal pod autoscaler (HPA) that monitors the resource demand and automatically scale the number of replicas. Also, based on the varying demands from the pods, the cluster autoscaler of kubernetes adjusts the number of nodes based on the compute resource requirements.

Clubbing ACI along with AKS form a powerful deployment model for microservices where AKS can be for typical deployment of microservices and ACIs for handling the burst workloads thereby reducing the challenges in management of scaling and ensuring effective utilization of the per second usage cost model.

Also, in case, if the requirement is some extension to existing azure application with event trigger based use cases, the azure functions can be better choice . Here, the specific code (function) shall be invoked only for specific event or trigger as per requirement and the function instances are created, destroyed on demand (compute on demand - function as a service (FaaS)). Azure function avoids allocation of extra resources (VMs) and also the cost is considered only when the function is processing work. Solutions can club both the functionalities such that Azure function shall be triggered for minimal processing / decision making and inturn can invoke Azure container instance for specific burst processing / complete processing which can be of lesser cost.

Answer (score 0):

There have been numerous proposals related to this functionality, but none have been incorporated into kubernetes.

Idle/Un-idle proposals:

1. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/3247
2. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/29471
3. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/42255

It is a difficult problem since the incoming requests would need to be queued while the service is spun-up.

If you're interested in implementing this functionality, it looks like some of the work has been done for you already, however it is not necessarily an end-to-end solution for your use case: https://github.com/openshift/service-idler

Here is another project which addresses similar capability: https://github.com/deislabs/osiris